# How to Compile FFmpeg in vs2019?

Tags: ffmpeg, visual-studio-2019

I have tried many ways to find from Google, but all failed. I want to compile my own ffmpeg library under win10 so that I can easily debug to see the problem when using ffmpeg.
Can anyone tell me a compilation method that still works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I don't complie ffmpeg in win10 by vs2019,I use msys2 and mingw.
If Someone want to complie ffmpeg in win10 same as me,can refer this url.
[ffmpeg in windows](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MinGW)